# jQuery pass url variable into load function

Tags: jquery, variables, load

I'm trying to use load to reload a portion of the current page (long story why) but am having an issue with the variable syntax.

Here is the snippet of code:

```
var pathname = window.location.pathname;
$('#menu').load("/cms.php #menu");
```

I woudl like to replace /cms.php with the variable, but am having issues with the corrent syntax.

Any help/advice would be much appricated.

A.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Just came across my own question (posted months ago). Easiest way is:

```
$('a').click(function() {
 $('#copy').load(this+"#cms");
 return false;
});
```

Answer (score 7):

Based on your example, to add in the pathname var just do the following, although why have you specified "#menu' at the end of the Load string.

```
var pathname = window.location.pathname; 
$('#menu').load(pathname +" #menu");
```

Answer (score 3):

May be you can try :

```
var pathname = window.location.pathname;
$('#menu').load(pathname+' #menu');
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var pathname = window.location.pathname; 
$('#menu').load(pathname+" #menu");
```

should do the job